# architechtetural thoughts about dockerizing the exsting services

Tags: jenkins, docker

we are in the process of dockerizing existing services those use kafka, storm 
and the expectation is use to create dockerized builds by integrating with jenkins .

I happened to look at a couple of articles http://blog.howareyou.com/post/62157486858/continuous-delivery-with-docker-and-jenkins-part, they are helpful.

I wanted to know the experiences with docker and how much time it took for the dockerizing a typical solution. And are there any best practices ?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of best practices: https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/

I think the "time to dockerize" will depend a lot on how familiar you are with linux. If you're already used to setting up linux systems, it should be pretty fast.